# {{ user:username }} not always returning right username

Tags: php, pyrocms

I am using **Pyro CMS** and implementing its custom module.

In this module when I am to get the user name by `{{user:username}}` it returns wrong value.
So I want to ask that is it correct way to get username or here is any error.

I there any other way to get the username in pyroCMS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might want is `{{ user:display_name }}`.

[Here is a list of all of the user variables available](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/index.php/modules-and-tags/tag-reference/user).

Comment: Thanks for the edit Uwe. I'll remember to link the text next time. :)